# How to get distinct random values in java?

Tags: java

Here is my problem: I have an array of integers, I would recover 20% of the array elements in a random manner. Is there a function in java to have more than a random value?
I tested for only one value:

```
Random rand=new Random();
int min=0, max=10;
int valeur = rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. What is your desired input and output?

Comment: didnt get your point..??

Comment: What do you mean by more than a random value?

Comment: i'd like 2 random value differents. if i try to iterate, perhaps i will have the same value or i'd like 2 values differents from the buffer

Comment: @user1568840 I'm taking it as...given an array, construct another where the size of the new one is 20% of the original, while containing a random sample of values of the other that are all distinct. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will prevent numbers being used twice and will get 20%:

```
    int[] nums = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    Random random = new Random();

    int numsFound = 0;
    int twentyPercent = (int)(nums.length/5F);
    List<Integer> usedIndices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (numsFound < twentyPercent) {
        int index = random.nextInt(nums.length);

        if (!usedIndices.contains(index)) { // not already used?
            System.out.println(nums[index]);
            usedIndices.add(index);
            numsFound++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: List<Integer> usedIndices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
or ArrayList<Integer> usedIndices = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Comment: The first form is better as it allows you to easily swap the list for another implementation later if required.

Comment: Or you could use `Collections.shuffle()` ;)

Comment: with List i have this error The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Integer>, with ArrayList it works

Comment: Are you importing java.util.List ?

Comment: please i didn't indersatnd  int twentyPercent =(int)(nums.length/5F);if i want 30% for example how can i change it?

Comment: Would it be better to use a LinkedList for this?  Assuming .contains() is O(N) for both and adding to a LinkedList is O(1) compared to O(N) for an ArrayList.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to get random but distinct values is to use shuffle.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = min; i <= max; i++) list.add(i);
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

You can iterate over `list` and get unique numbers in a random order.

You can even using this approach if you want not more than two of something and three of something else by adding the number you wan to the list.

BTW: This approach is O(n) for n numbers whereas generating random numbers and checking if they are there already is O(n^2 * log(n)) which is much slower.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question right, you are trying to obtain a "random" array. If so, you can use the following:

```
int nrOfValues = 20;
int[] values = new int[nrOfValues];
for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
{
    values[i] = rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
}
```

If you would like to obtain *distinct* random values, try the following:

```
ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int nrOfValues = 20;
for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
{
    int value = rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    while(values.contains(value))
        value = rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    values.add(value);
}
```

Of course, if `min` and `max` are poorly chosen, you might end up with an infinite loop...

Comment: with this solution, perhaps i have the same value twice ??

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Dice 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Initialize Variables and Array
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] numbers = new int[10];
        int min = 0, max = 10;


        // Input Random Number Into 10 Elements Of Array
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
            numbers[i] = rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;


        // Output 10 Array Cells
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
            System.out.println(numbers[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didnt quite understand the question..

from what i understood you need something like this

```
List<Integer> listOfRandomNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
//Initialize this List with required numbers

int numberOfRandomNumbersNeeded = listOfRandomNumbers/5;
int min = 0; 
int max = listOfRandomNumbers.size() - 1;

Random rand = new Random();
Set<Integer> randomNumbers = new HashSet<Integer>();
while(randomNumbers.size() < numberOfRandomNumbersNeeded) {
int value = rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
randomNumbers.add(listOfRandomNumbers.get(value));
}

System.out.println(randomNumbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private Integer[] recover(double percentage, Integer[] ints) {
    int numberOfElementsToRecover = (int) (ints.length*percentage);
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(ints);
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(list.toArray(new Integer[]{}), 0, numberOfElementsToRecover);
}
```